# How to obtain file path from find with variable filename

Tags: bash, variables, find

I have a command that works fine as is:

```
fname=$(find $dir -name '*001.txt')
```

What I would like to do is replace the number by a variable:

```
fname=$(find $dir -name '*$num.txt')
```

but get nothing. I have tried escaping the single quotes: `\'*$num.txt\'`, enclosing the single quotes in double quotes: `"'"*$num.txt"'",` but nothing works. What do I need?

Comment: Shell variables don't expand in single quotes. Globs don't expand in any quotes. You need to double quote the variable and not quote the glob (`*`).

Comment: As, Cyrus realized correctly and I wasn't thinking clearly about that glob doesn't want to be expanded by the shell you want `find` to see it unexpanded so keep the `*` in the double quotes as indicated. Do be aware though that this isn't a safe way to get multiple filenames back if you want to use them one-by-one. For that you need a `while` loop (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for more details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fname=$(find $dir -name "*${num}.txt")
```